# Node.JS module.exports for passing parameter between two functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to Node.js so this is probably a fundamental question and I am missing something obvious. In the code below, I am trying to set the sql_file name from foo but I keep getting an error on the file not existing because the variable is not working. If I hard code the file name in sql_util.js it works fine.

So how do I pass a parameter or any object from one js file into the function of another?

**foo.js**

```
var misc = require('./sql_get');
console.log(misc.sql_file("on.sql"));
```

**sql_util.js**

```
fs = require('fs');
file = 'on.sql'
function sql_file(cb) {
    var fileName = "./SQLs/" + sql_file;
    fs.readFile(fileName, function(err, buffer) {
        if (err) return cb(err);
        return cb(null, buffer.toString());
    });
}
sql_file(function(err, sqlstatement) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('sql statement is: ' + sqlstatement);
});
};
module.exports.x = x;
module.exports.sql_fil = sql_file;
```

Comment: what's with the *'s around variable/property names?

Comment: suppose to be bold. thanks

Comment: This code is full of typos, undefined variable references and incorrect file names.  I suggest cleaning up the code first and see if it works, then worry about parameter passing.

Comment: Like I said, I am new to this so I appreciate the feedback, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's go through this line by line because I see a lot of errors, both syntax and semantic.

**foo.js**

```
var misc = require('./sql_get');
console.log(misc.sql_file("on.sql"));
```

You defined in the function below `sql_file` to be asynchronous, so it does not return a value, but takes a callback that it passes the result to.

**sql_util.js**

```
fs = require('fs');
file = 'on.sql'
```

You have an unused module-global variable `file`.  Remove this.  It's going to cause confusion.

```
function sql_file(cb) {
    var fileName = "./SQLs/" + sql_file;
```

`sql_file` is a function.  I can tell because this code lives in a function called `sql_file`.  Therefore, fileName will be "./SQLs/" + the `.toString()` result of the function, which is the source of the function.  I think perhaps you want a parameter?

```
    fs.readFile(fileName, function(err, buffer) {
        if (err) return cb(err);
        return cb(null, buffer.toString());
    });
}
```

This seems ok.

```
sql_file(function(err, sqlstatement) {
    if (err) throw err;
        console.log('sql statement is: ' + sqlstatement);
    });
};
```

I am not sure what you are trying to do here.  Why are you calling the function?

```
module.exports.x = x;
module.exports.sql_fil = sql_file;
```

Both of these lines have a problem.  There is no symbol defined named `x`.  I am surprised this code runs without throwing an error on that line.  Second, you are exporting `sql_file` as `sql_fil`, missing the letter e.

**The Solution**

Since what you asked about is parameter passing and you only have a single function, let's simplify this.  You never want to use global variables.  If a function needs a particular variable, just pass it as an argument.

**foo.js**

```
var misc = require('./sql_get');
misc.sql_file('on.sql', function (err, contents) {
    console.log(contents);
});
```

**sql_get.js** (notice the file is renamed)

```
var fs = require('fs');

function sql_file(sqlFilename, cb) {
    var fileName = "./SQLs/" + sqlFilename;
    fs.readFile(fileName, function(err, buffer) {
        if (err) return cb(err);
        return cb(null, buffer.toString());
    });
}

module.exports.sql_file = sql_file;
```

Comment: Brandon, I am coming from a Visual Basic world and it is just such a learning curve, I have been reading Node.ja in Action, it is good but a bit over my head. Today I have Sams learn Node.Js. Really its the fundamentals that you point out that I need to focus on. I have only been working in js for about a week now so your feedback was great, thanks for taking the time! It there is any other good literature or exercises you can recommend I would be grateful.. Thanks again

Comment: Sure.  JavaScript and node.js in particular are single-threaded and the trick to scaling concurrency is asynchronous I/O with callbacks.  I suggest studying callbacks since there is probably no exposure to it in VB.

Answer (score 3):

A few problems:

1. You're requiring sql_get but naming the other file sql_util

   ```
   var misc = require('./sql_util');
   ```
2. You're exporting `module.exports.sql_fil = sql_file;` (see the missing `e`). You probably mean;

   ```
   module.exports.sql_file = sql_file;
   ```
3. While calling sql_file, you are passing a string but expecting a cb in the function itself -

   ```
   misc.sql_file("on.sql", function(err, fileContent) {
       if(err) return console.log(err);
       console.log('File content: ', fileContent);
   });

   function sql_file(sqlFileName, cb) {
       var fileName = "./SQLs/" + sqlFileName;
       fs.readFile(fileName, function(err, buffer) {
           if (err) return cb(err);
           return cb(null, buffer.toString());
       });
   }
   ```

And I don't know what you are doing with calling sql_file function in that file itself. Remove that.

Comment: I want to put the call back into var reader = connection.reader("SELECT * FROM ON", []) to keep the code neat so it looks like connection.reader(sql_file("on.sql")). Reading the raw sql file and use the select right from the sql file.